# Powershell: Get all ADUsers from a list, with a specific E-Maildomain and has not logged in in 90 days

Tags: powershell

Im trying to write a script that goes through a CSV-File, searches up the Username in our AD and then gives me these users, that have a specific E-Maildomain and hasn't logged in for the last 90 days.

Here's what I got so far:

```
import-csv C:\pathtofile\user.csv | ForEach-Object {
Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName -Filter "EMailAddress -like '*@thedomain.com'" -Properties SamAccountName,LastLogonDate | Where  {  ($_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)) -and ($_.LastLogonDate -ne $NULL)} | Sort | Select Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate
}
```

But it gives me this weird error:

> Get-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Username'.

I tried to put the E-Mailsorting into my where-statement, but it was not able to find any users then...

Can you guys may see what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Kind regards,

Gabe

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use parameter `-Filter` together with `-Identity`.
(using `Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName` implicitely uses the `-Identity` parameter)

To filter out only users that are in your CSV file AND that have a specific domain in their email address, you can do:

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90).Date  # set to midnight
$result  = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\pathtofile\user.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $userSam = $_.SamAccountName
    try {
        $user = Get-ADUser $userSam -Properties EmailAddress, LastLogonDate -ErrorAction Stop
        if (($user.LastLogonDate) -and $user.LastLogonDate -lt $refDate -and
             $user.EmailAddress -like '*@thedomain.com') {
            $user | Select-Object Name,SamAccountName,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "User '$userSam' not found"
    }
}
```

To filter out all users that have a specific domain in their email address, so not using the csv at all, you can do:

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90).Date  # set to midnight
$result  = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -like '*@thedomain.com'" -Properties EmailAddress, LastLogonDate |
Where-Object { ($_.LastLogonDate) -and $_.LastLogonDate -lt $refDate } |
Select-Object Name,SamAccountName,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate | Sort-Object Name
```

```
# show the result on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize
# and/or save to a new csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\pathtofile\filteredusers.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```